# Intercept Ajax form before sending

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, preventdefault

I am using a CMS that creates a form and sends it via AJAX. I'd like to validate the inputs before, but cannot prevent it from sending, because the CMS binds sending on the submit event.

```
bind(form, "submit", function(e){
  …
})
```

I thought this would stop it and I can validate my inputs.

```
$( ".contact-form form" ).on('submit', function(e){
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
})
```

But even stopImmediatePropagation() won't prevent sending.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
    $( ".contact-form form" ).on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    })
```

or

```
    $( ".contact-form form" ).on('submit', function(e){
      return false;
    })
```

Here's the difference between the two...
[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Hope that helps

Comment: Had both tested and it keeps submitting the form.

Comment: Based on the code you posted my next move would be within your bind(form, "submit", function(e){...}) to add something like...if($(this).hasClass("contact-form form")){e.preventDefault;} and remove your on submit event

Comment: That means editing the core files of the CMS. I hoped there is a way to hijack it from my jQuery code.